OLEDBDataAdaptor.Fill method runs incredibly slowly
I have a complex SQL query that runs instantly in MS Access.
When I run the same query in VB.Net the OLEDB.Fill method hangs for up to 10 minutes. I eventually get back the same 1500 records returned in Access but it is too slow.
The query returns invoices that have an outstanding balance.
Lines on the invoices are stored in the Entries table that are joined to the Journal table, that is joined to the Invoices table. To work out whether an invoice has been paid or not we need to add all the invoice cost centre entries and the payment entries. The query text can also be modified for example to find invoices for any particular supplier, but this just changes the WHERE clause without affecting the SELECT.
The Entries table has around 370.000 rows, the Journal table around 150.000 and around 65.000. There are indexes on the tables for every field used in the join statements. I've already done multiple compact and repairs on the database. I need the whole datatable to display the results in a datagridview so a datareader would not work?
I am rewriting the software using C# instead of VB and using SQL server instead of Access, however that is going to take some time and I need a solution in the interim.
Here is the query:
SELECT invoices.id,
       jobs.id AS [Job ID],
       jobs.datestart AS [Job Date],
       locations.locationname AS LOCATION,
       invoices.invoicedate,
       invoices.duedate,
       invoices.invoiceno,
       Clients.entityname AS Client,
       xinvoicetype.description AS TYPE,
       Payers.entityname AS Payer,
       Payees.entityname AS Payee,
       xinvoicestatus.description AS Status,
       Costs.[nett],
       Costs.tax AS GST,
       Costs.nett + Costs.tax AS Total,
       Iif(Isnull(Payments.paid), 0, Payments.paid) AS Paid,
       Costs.nett + Costs.tax - Iif(Isnull(Payments.paid), 0, Payments.paid) AS Balance,
       xdoctypes.description AS [Next Doc],
       invoices.nextdocdue
FROM ((((((((((invoices
               INNER JOIN entities AS Payers ON invoices.payerid = Payers.id)
              INNER JOIN entities AS Payees ON invoices.payeeid = Payees.id)
             INNER JOIN xinvoicetype ON invoices.invoicetype = xinvoicetype.id)
            INNER JOIN xinvoicestatus ON invoices.status = xinvoicestatus.id)
           INNER JOIN xdoctypes ON invoices.nextdoctype = xdoctypes.id)
          LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT invoiceid,
                    Sum(amount) AS Nett,
                    Sum(gst) AS Tax
             FROM entries
             INNER JOIN journal ON entries.journalid = journal.id
             WHERE entrytype < 6 GROUP  BY invoiceid) AS Costs ON Costs.invoiceid = invoices.id)
         LEFT JOIN
           (SELECT invoiceid,
                   Sum(amount * -1) AS Paid
            FROM entries
            INNER JOIN journal ON entries.journalid = journal.id
            WHERE entrytype BETWEEN 7 AND 8 GROUP  BY invoiceid) AS Payments ON Payments.invoiceid = invoices.id)
        LEFT JOIN jobs ON invoices.jobid = jobs.id)
       LEFT JOIN entities AS Clients ON jobs.clientid = Clients.id)
      LEFT JOIN sessions ON jobs.sessionid = sessions.id)
LEFT JOIN locations ON sessions.locationid = locations.id
WHERE NOT(Costs.nett + Costs.tax - Iif(Isnull(Payments.paid), 0, Payments.paid) BETWEEN -0.011 AND .0099);

Here is the code:
Using cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & gstrConnectionMain & ";Persist Security Info=False")
    Using dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        Using da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, cnn)
            Dim unused = da.Fill(dt)
            grd.DataSource = dt
        End Using
    End Using
End Using

As mentioned, the query works instantly in Ms-Access but abysmally slowly in VB. Any pointers gratefully received.

that is not the problem of the oledb adapter, you are using an ancient version, look if version 12 or newer give better perofimance3

Are you sure the query is running slower? Remember, in the Access UI, it is able to display records before the whole query has completed. I would test the query using VBA and a DAO recordset, and toss in a move last to ensure you pulled the whole query data set. And your "where" clause is not what we call "sargeable" in that indexing can't be used.  If you can add some date range, or use a expression that indexing can use, then this will run much faster, but your where clause is a non indexable expression. Using a older or newer version of the data engine not going help speed here.

Thanks. I've installed ACE.16.0 which opened up a whole can of worms because some of the computers needed an executable for '86' and others for 'any cpu' to get it working. With ACE.16.0 the query now takes around 30s to execute, better but still too slow. I have the date ranges in the two subqueries, presumably these are "sargable?" I'm a novice at databases, is there some better way to work out which invoices have/have not been paid without resorting to storing the "balance" in the invoice table itself - which would violate normalization?
